Water valve not shutting off - how and what to replace?
What is the name of this valve? I know speedy valves and quarter valves, but I don't know the specific name of that one.
It opens and closes but when fully closed, water is still running. After turning off incoming water for the apartment, how to replace this valve? Just unscrew the front and insert new valve? Or does it need any extra work? Would you replace this type of valve for a better one, or keep the same type of valve?



I have never seen those specific valves before, however It leeds me to believe that there is a washer that seals against a seat.  The washer would most likely  need to be replaced.  Removing the handle and coller will give a better idea of the remaining process.  Would i replace the entire valve?  I don't know. because I'm not aware of the entire situation.

Huh?  Is the feed line internal or something?

As @rmdman said in the comments first step would be to try replacing the valve washer, which usually means removing the valve stem, which starts by turning off the water supply, removing the handle and cover plate so you can access the top of the valve and use a wrench to remove it. Then remove the screw which holds the washer, install a suitable replacement, reassemble and check for leaks and proper operation.
But I'll note here that this task has a bad habit of becoming more complicated. The cave stem may want repacking. The valve seat may be eroded and also need to be replaced. It's not unheard of for old cheap valves to break while you're trying to do this, resulting in having to open the wall and replace the entire valve after all.
So this is not something I would recommend as a beginner plumbing project; if it goes wrong you may be without water for several days (depending on where you were able to turn it off). You might want to consider leaving this one to a pro.
